# SQL Exception by using a prepared statement

Tags: android, prepared-statement

Maybe you will help me furthermore, it would be very nice :-D then I get this code in my Activity where I want to show this details in another textview. So I open the task but I don't even see the Message in System.out.println in the LogCat. How can I use it correctly?

```
public static TextView auswahl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beschreibung);

    auswahl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtauswahl);
    auswahl.setText(GlossarFragment.keyword); 

    //Öffnen des SQL Befehls zum Einlesen des Eintrages
    GetBeschreibungFromDBAsyncTask task = new GetBeschreibungFromDBAsyncTask();
    task.execute();

    List<String> res;
    try {
        res = task.get();
        for(String s:res) {
            System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA: " + s);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Automatisch generierter Erfassungsblock
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Automatisch generierter Erfassungsblock
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

This is the task to get the description out of the database.

```
public class GetBeschreibungFromDBAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,List<String>> {

    private static String QUERY = "SELECT \"Beschreibung\" FROM \"Glossar\" WHERE \"Name\" = ?;";
    private String ausw;  

    @Override
    //im Hintergrund die SQL Abfrage ausgeführt und die Ergebnisse in die Liste eingelesen
    protected List<String> doInBackground(String... params) {

        ausw = BeschreibungActivity.auswahl.toString();

        List<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Connection conn;
            conn = JdbcConnectionManager.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement prepState = conn.prepareStatement(QUERY);
            prepState.setString(1, ausw);
            ResultSet resSet = prepState.executeQuery();

            while(resSet.next()) {
                res.add(resSet.getString(1));
            }

            prepState.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            //bei einem Fehler in der SQL Anweisung
            System.out.println("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS");
            sqle.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to declare a parameter is to use `?`, like `where someColumnn = ?`

By the way, what kind of database are you trying to use ? JDBC it's probably not the best way to use a locale SQLite db (I didn't even know that it was supported).

Comment: well I know, it is such a emergency solution. It's just a project for school ;-)

Comment: could you also tell me how should I do this with more parameters? like in an INSERT Query? 
private static String QUERY = "INSERT INTO \"User\"(\"ID\", \"EMail\", \"Ort\", \"Passwort\") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ;";

Comment: you can use multiple `?` then set the values using setString(1, XXX), setString(2, YYYY), ...